# Session Snapshots like the Virtualbox's but native to the OS

Tags: cross-platform, virtualization

Is there a software that provides support for Session Snapshots which is commonly found in virtualization software like [virtualbox](http://virtualbox.org)?

It would let you save a "state" of all your opened applications and their associated data. You could then either come back to it or branch off of it and switch between two saved states to find your programs and their data just as when you saved them.

Sort of like Git, but for the entire OS.

My first preference would be a Windows' software but any OS would do. Even if it has to be an entire OS that lets you do this natively please recommend that as well. I'm inclined to believe no software alone would be able to provide such a feature.

[image]

Comment: On Linux, that's in the realm of "windows managers". I rarely reboot (only for kernel updates), so I've not played with this and cannot tell which WM supports it best (never was my prio-1 feature). From the few times I've tried (long ago), it always seemed to miss a window or two – but they might have "perfected" that. Watch for "session restore". I'm just not sure if you can save *any* state, or whether it only saves on exit/shutdown.

Comment: I don't know of anything like this (hdd + apps). With regards to the hard disk you gave zfs/btrfs/lvm snapshots. But why can't you simply use virtualbox?